# Laravel edit form can't update child/parent row

Tags: php, laravel

Im new to laravel and i want to make an update function but it doesn t work. I get my update form correctly but when i submit it i get an error that says it can t updata a parent/child row

This is my function

```
public function update($verhaal, $wereld) 
{
    $wereld = Werelden::where('wereld_id', $wereld)->update([
            'wereld_id' => $wereld,
            'naam' => 'naam',
            'beschrijving' => 'beschrijving',
            'verhaal_id' => 'verhaal_id'
        ]);


    return redirect('/');
}
```

This are my routes

```
Route::get('verhalen/{verhaal}/bekijken/{wereld}/edit', 'WereldController@BewerkWereld');
Route::put('verhalen/{verhaal}/bekijken/{wereld}/edit', 'WereldController@update');
```

And as last i have my html form

```
<div class="panel-body">
        @include('common.errors')
        <form action="{{ url('/verhalen/'. $wereld->verhaal_id .'/bekijken/'. $wereld->wereld_id .'/edit')}} " method="POST">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            {{ method_field('PUT') }}
            <input type="text" class="form-control verhaal-toevoegen" value="{{ $wereld->naam }}" name="naam">
            <textarea class="form-control" id="verhaal-text" name="verhaal">{{ $wereld->beschrijving}}</textarea>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Verhaal bijwerken</button>
        </form> 
</div>
```

I hope someone can help me

Comment: Can you try with this:

`$wereld = Werelden::where('wereld_id', $wereld)->update([
            'naam' => 'naam',
            'beschrijving' => 'beschrijving',
        ]);`

Comment: i tried but it didn t work

Comment: Show us your model, have you set your `$fillable` right?

Comment: What does the error say...

Answer (score 0):

```
public function update($verhaal, $wereld) 
{
    $wereld = Werelden::where('wereld_id', $wereld)->update([
            'wereld_id' => $wereld,
            'naam' => 'naam',
            'beschrijving' => 'beschrijving',
            'verhaal_id' => $verhaal_id // "verhaal_id" It is not an id 
        ]);


    return redirect('/');
}
```

uses columns necesaries only

```
    $wereld = Werelden::where('wereld_id', $wereld)->update([
            'wereld_id' => $wereld,
            'naam' => 'naam',
            'beschrijving' => 'beschrijving',
        ]);
```